# Session cookie with httpOnly flag

Tags: tomcat, grails, session-cookies, httponly

I would like to configure my grails project in such a way that the session cookie is set with the httpOnly flag.

As I do understand, this is a configuration in the web.xml or context.xml file. But how do I set it in my grails project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are a few ways to do it according to [this blog post](http://sylvanvonstuppe.blogspot.com/2007/07/servlet-filter-for-httponly.html) (author of *The Definitive Guide to Grails* commented on that post). But it looks like there isn't any straightforward way to do it.